# Form not getting submitted from jQuery Validation Plugin's submitHandler

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

```
submitHandler: function (form)
{
    form.submit();   //         jQuery(form).submit();
    window.close();
}
```

I am using the above `submitHandler` in validating my form through jQuery validation plugin, but the form is not getting submitted. But, if I use the commented line instead, then the form is submitted but browser shows the following dialog and starts to become unresponsive, although on terminating the script by clicking "yes", the form data had been saved and window does not close.

```
"Stop running this script?"
"A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly.
 If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive."

          "Yes"    "No"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commented line is an example of the [too much recursion](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation#Too_much_recursion) problem explained in the jQuery validation docs.

Why the usual `form.submit()` does not work in your case is a bit difficult to tell without more example code. It's possible that calling `window.close()` aborts the form submission?

Comment: But, if I use form.submit(); without calling window.close(); then also, the form is not getting submitted.

Comment: Well, as I said, it's difficult to tell what the problem is without example code. That was just my best guess given what little you did post. Create a jsFiddle using as little code as possible that reproduces the problem, and we can debug it from there.

Comment: Although I have found an other way around for doing this same thing, but still I would like to do it in this way also so that it helps in future if required, so I will go for your comments and create a jsFiddle when I get free time and we will debug that. I have upvoted the answer but still not accepted because I want to work on it and solve it in this way. Many thanks.